# Excel delimited file

Tags: python, macos, excel, delimiter, textedit

I have an excel file that contains data with multiple columns of varying width that I need to work with on my PC. However, the file contains SOH and STX characters as delimiting characters, since they were from TextEdit on a Mac. The SOH is record delimiter and the STX is row delimiter. On my PC, both these characters are shown as a rectangle (in screenshot). I can't use the fixed width delimited option since I would lose data. I tried writing a Python script, but Python doesn't recognize the SOH and STX either, just displays it as a rectangle too. How do I delimit these records appropriately? I would appreciate any possible method.
Thanks!

[image: Actual text file]

[image]

Comment: What do you want? Read the values? Write them back? Just display? Please, elaborate. An show your code!

Comment: I would like the values to be written back to the Excel file, or any new file, in the appropriate delimited format. The script I wrote is basic to just read the contents of the file, which is file.read().

Comment: You should be able to refer to SOH and STX control characters by their ASCII values in Python: `'\x01'`, and `'\x02'` respectively. Apparently the `csv` module doesn't actually support custom line endings (it's hard coded to look for some combination of `'\n'` and `'\r'`), but I'm not convinced that your text doesn't have actual newlines in addition to the STXs, given that your data appears on multiple lines in your screenshot. Can you provide some of the actual text data, rather than just a screenshot of it in your editor?

Comment: I can't refer to SOH and STX in ASCII in Python. I tried and it didn't make any difference. I have added some of the actual text data in the original post above.

Comment: @Nathan822: Um, that's another screenshot, not text. I was hoping for text that I can copy and paste!

Comment: Sorry! Here you go:

1392061514090254939881059
139206151409059699439110343
13920615140904353530709765
139206151409083239294484388
139206151409025504823290319
1392061514090424977444182448
13920615140904080300182447
13920615140906300845852345651
13920615140901335229282004323
13920615140903737183182749
13920615140902775975841708
1392061514090777806798686267
1392061514090209206472263798
1392061514090257086328239
139206151409024706632027
13920615140902628961611045526
139206151409089225381901441

Comment: That's weird. It seems normal here.

Comment: StackOverflow comments may not allow control characters. You could see if they work in the question body, or if they get filtered there too, you could upload to some external site and give a link.

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
SOH='\x01'
STX='\x02'

# As it is, this function returns the values as strings, not as integers
def read_lines(filename):
    rawdata = open(filename, "rb").read()
    for l in rawdata.split(SOH + STX):
        if not l:
            continue
        yield l.split(SOH)

# Rows is a list. Each element in the list is a row of values
# (either a list or a tuple, for example)
def write_lines(filename, rows):
    with open(filename, "wb") as f:
        for row in rows:
             f.write(SOH.join([str(x) for x in row]) + SOH + STX)
```

Edit: Example use...

```
for row in read_lines("myfile.csv"):
    print ", ".join(row)
```

Comment: I provided functions to read and write the file. You need to use them!

Comment: NameError: global name 'read' is not defined. Line 8, which is
for line in read.split(SOH + STX):

Should it be rawdata.split?

Comment: Yes, it should be. I wrote the code straight here, so it can have a few mistakes

Comment: Fixed. As a bonus, I modified the `read_lines` function to work as a generator, instead of returning the whole piece of data in one go.